# G++ linker silently ignores a library

Tags: linker, g++, linker-errors, ld

I need to link an object file with libraries into an executable but I keep getting undefined reference errors due to the linker using a wrong library version. The linker command is pretty straight forward, here is the simplified version:

```bash
g++ main.cpp.o -o main -Wl,-rpath,/path-to-dir/lib64:/path-to-dependency/lib: lib64/libWithDependencies.so -Wl,-rpath-link,/path-to-dependency/lib
```

When I run it with `-Wl,--verbose`, I see the standard procedure of searching the library with a weird issue. I need to link `/path-to-dependency/lib/libINeed.so`. However, in the procedure of searching:

1. in `-rpath-link` directories
2. in `-rpath` directories
3. in the current working directory
4. in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
5. etc.

It ignores (does not print anything about) the `/path-to-dependency/lib` when searching `libINeed.so` and instead fallbacks for `/usr/lib64/dependency/lib/libINeed.so` which is of a much older version. The directory path is present in `-rpath-link` and in `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. The weird thing is that it checks the directory for all the other libraries and even uses some of them. This lead me to believe that it is an issue with the file but again I got no message about the linker accessing it.

It should not be an issue with versions as the names match:

```bash
readelf -d lib64/libWithDependecies.so | grep libINeed.so
# 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libINeed.so]
readelf -d /path-to-dependency/lib/libINeed.so | grep SONAME
# 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libINeed.so]
readelf -d /usr/lib64/dependency/libINeed.so | grep SONAME
# 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libINeed.so.6.24]
```

Even more strangely, when I run `ldd` it finds the correct path:

```bash
ldd lib64/libWithDependencies.so | grep libINeed.so
#        libINeed.so => /path-to-dependency/lib/libINeed.so (0x00007f42b2aa4000)
```

What could be the reason for the linker to just ignore the library and not print a single word about it?